# Просвечивает view через Layout

Tags: android, android-layout

Если layout1 (ConstraintLayout) развернут на весь экран. Под layout1 находится layout2 (ConstraintLayout) у которого есть view (ConstraintLayout) с elevation = 2dp, этот view просвечивается через layout1, если у view убрать elevation = 0, то view становится нормальным и его не видно под layout1. Можно что-нибудь указать layout1, чтобы экран скрывался полностью и при этом не трогать elevation у view ?

Comment: `layout2.setVisibility(View.GONE);`

Comment: Ну да и так скрываю, просто интересно почему такая логика поведения, если elevation, то просвечивает

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Единственный способ в вашем случае - `layout2.setVisibility(View.GONE);`

Для понимания того, как работает elevation:

[image: результат]

Comment: Теперь всё понятно, большое спасибо.

Comment: @cooper_so если ответ верный нажмите на галочку слева от ответа